# How does a body corporate get sentenced for criminal offences?

Tags: criminal-law, england-and-wales, incorporation

Some criminal offences specifically state that if they are committed by the officer of a body corporate then they along with the body corporate itself may be simultaneously processed against as well as each other.

They are further specified to be punishable on indictment to X years in prison.

Does the prison term get translated according to some scale as a fine in case of a corporate defendant?

Further, can bodies corporate be tried in magistrate as well as crown court?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

Corporations are subject to the monetary fines in the *Criminal Code* or relevant Act. See "[Criminal Liability of Organizations: A Plain Language Guide to Bill C-45](https://www.justice.gc.ca/eng/rp-pr/other-autre/c45/c45.pdf)." Factors specific to the sentencing of organizations are found at [s. 718.21](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/c-46/page-114.html#docCont). Corporations can be tried in both [provincial courts and superior courts](https://www.justice.gc.ca/eng/csj-sjc/just/07.html).